# urdu fonts are not working online but working offline in localhost wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, codeigniter, pdf, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

I am creating a pdf report using `wkhtmltopdf` using urdu fonts in it 
font-family is

```
font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq, Nafees Web Naskh, Arial, Urdu Naskh Asiatype, Tahoma, Unicode MS !important'
```

I have added this in my css in the body tag and it is working fine in local but when I am opening this report in production it shows boxex rather than the urdu words, it is not picking up the fonts in production

I have also tried using

```
@font-face {
               font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq, Nafees Web Naskh, Arial, Urdu Naskh Asiatype, Tahoma, Unicode MS !important';
               src: url('http://www.example.com/font/Jamel.ttf') format('truetype');
          }
```

but it is not working either.
can anyone help me...?

Answer (score 1):

i face the same problem .
1.step :download the font from [here](http://download885.mediafire.com/gjef3cagbd6g/s5j5f2ob889k38u/Fonts.rar)

2.step :define in css

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"Jameel Noori Nastaleeq";
  src:url("../font/urdu_fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf");
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

3.step :now use like

```
body{
    font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq' ,'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this and will let you know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this `font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq', 'Nafees Web Naskh', 'Urdu Naskh Asiatype', Arial, Tahoma, Unicode MS !important';`